# Render network with nodes on top

Tags: r, shiny, nodes, igraph, vis.js

I'm trying to ensure that certain nodes are always rendered on top of other nodes and am having a hard time doing so. Is this possible?

I'm using visNetwork with shiny and want visIgraph for the drl layout. It is possible to render nodes on top of other nodes using igraph alone as igraph draws nodes as they appear in the data; this doesn't appear to be the case with visNetwork

In the code below, I would like to get the group 'Other Group' to be always rendered on top of 'Blue Group'; the smaller nodes will be rendered above the larger nodes.

```
require(shiny)
require(visNetwork)
require(igraph)
require(gplots)

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:1000, color=colors()[350:449], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
nodes$group <- ifelse(grepl('blue',nodes$color), 'Blue Group', 'Other Group')
nodes$color <- col2hex(nodes$color)
nodes$color.background <- nodes$color
edges <- data.frame(from = sample.int(1000,1500,replace=TRUE)
                    , to = sample.int(1000,1500,replace=TRUE))
g=graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed=FALSE, vertices=nodes)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$network <- renderVisNetwork({
    # minimal example
    withProgress(message = 'Making plot', value = .5, {
      visIgraph(igraph=g, layout = "layout_with_drl", randomSeed = 1
                , idToLabel=FALSE, type='square') %>% 
        visGroups(groupname = "Blue Group", value=5) %>%
        visGroups(groupname = "Other Group", value=3)
    })
  })
}
ui <- fluidPage(
  visNetworkOutput("network")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's currently not possible using `vis.js` and `visNetwork`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try hierarchical layout in vis.js, set some `level` value to Nodes, same hierarchy have same `level` value, here is [Nodes Options](http://visjs.org/docs/network/nodes.html), and you can refer to [hierarchicalLayoutWithoutPhysics](http://visjs.org/examples/network/layout/hierarchicalLayoutWithoutPhysics.html)